# Spring Controller not receiving 'page' param from request params for pagination

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a controller which has the following method

```
@GetMapping 
public Page<Routine> getAll(
    @RequestParam(required = false) String type,
    @RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") int page,
    @RequestParam(defaultValue = "10") int size){

    Pageable paging = PageRequest.of(page, size);
    return routineRepository.findByTypeAndSharedIsTrue(type, paging);
}
```

And the following repository

```
public interface RoutineRepository extends MongoRepository<Routine, String>{
    Page<Routine> findByTypeAndSharedIsTrue(String type, Pageable pageable);
}
```

When I make a request to that method: `curl http://localhost:1235/api/routines?type=Calisthenics`, the `page` parameter is set to 0 as it's its default value, after I try `curl http://localhost:1235/api/routines?type=Calisthenics&page=1` though, the `page` parameter doesn't change and it contains its default value `0` no matter which value I give it in the request

Comment: Note that you can use `Pageable` as a parameter type, and Spring will automatically create it from the query parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, if you use curl in command line and you want to use & sign to append parameters, you have to use

> \ &